# MVC route, query parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Two simple mvc3 routes, username and a default catch all.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Users", 
    "{username}",  
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index"} 
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{*url}", 
    new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" }  
);
```

How do you make the user route accept any extra query parameters like /username?ref=facebook
This example just heads of to default route...

EDIT:
MY BAD, was a bit surprised by this as it shouldn't care about query parameters.
Solution = clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Update your first route as follow:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Users", 
    "/username",  
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index"} 
);
```

In your controller Action add a parameter "ref" so that it MVC automatically passes the query string "ref" to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter to the route, and don't forget to add it to your action.
I would suggest adding something to the beginning of the urls to make it a bit more specific (in case you add any other routes to your project)
Example

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Users",
    "users/{username}/{ref}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index", ref = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and in your action you'd want

```
public ActionResult Index(ref)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ref))
    {
        //TODO: add your logic here
    }
}
```

This should accept /users/someusername/facebook.com OR /users/someusername?ref=facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Query string parameters like `?ref=` are not part of the Route segment definition. For example, a route llike:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", 
                "{controller}/{action}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
            );
```

Would still match a URL like: `/Home/Index?ref=facebook`.

So you don't have to change your routes to accommodate ad hoc Query String. Handling them in your Actions/Controller is a different story, because you will have to follow and CoC Convention over Configuration guidelines and match the Query String parameter in your Actions.